# Echo number of comments on blog

Tags: php, count

I'm making a blog where people can respond on. Now under the blog and above the comments. I want to display the number of comments that have been posted on that blog. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the php that shows the comments

```
<?php foreach($item->comments->find_all() as $comment) : ?>
                <?php echo View::factory('modules/comment', array(
                    'comment'   =>  $comment)); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count() Funktion:

```
 count( $item->comments->find_all() );
```

Or direct count your databaseentries with SQL (what is in my eyes the better solution solution). But i don't know your datamodel.
It would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Have a look at http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.count.php